# Can you embed google apps on your tumblr blog; if you do not have your own domain?

Tags: google-apps-script, tumblr, google-apps

Can you embed a google apps service on your tumblr blog, if you do not have your own domain?

Answer (score 1):

No. You cannot embed an Apps Script web app in an external site. You can only do it on a Google Site.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible I have installed google comments and google follower on my tumblr blog.

Comment: did you do any GAS coding or just embed APIs? can you post me the link so i can view them too? Thanks